# Traceview maximum record time?

Tags: android

I am using Debug.startMethodTracing and Debug.stopMethodTracing to optimize a piece of code that takes about 30 sec to execute but when I open the trace file with trace view it only shows me about 6.5 secondes of trace data.

Any clues ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The function `startMethodTracing` by default only logs 8MB of trace data. To get a longer trace, set the second parameter to the maximum trace size you want it to record (in bytes).

```
startMethodTracing("mytrace", 100000000);
```

Comment: Tks. I did not notice the second parameter. I accepted your answer and gave you a up vote. :o)

Answer (score 3):

The buffer is limited by the device ram. You cannot specify a too big buffer when calling Debug.startMethodTracing.

Comment: Is there any documentation to support this claim ?