# Android traceview not working or only logs 900 ms?

Tags: android, trace

In my default view I have:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Debug.startMethodTracing(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/PosLogistics.trace", 1000000000);
```

and do the stop here:

```
protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        Debug.stopMethodTracing();
    }
```

The android target is 2.2. When running on Motorolla 2.3 I can trace 900 ms. When running on Samsung Galaxy (4.0) and Sony Xperia (4.0) the app closes immediately as it starts up. Last entry from logcat is

02-15 05:25:19.940: I/dalvikvm(8740): TRACE STARTED: '/mnt/sdcard/PosLogistics.trace' 976562KB

According to this thread: [Traceview maximum record time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518393/traceview-maximum-record-time) the trace is limited by the device RAM. Might explain the Motorolla 900 ms, but what is the problem with the Galaxy and Xperia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You are trying to allocate `1000000000` bytes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#startMethodTracing%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) ~ 1GB for trace buffer. I don't think any system will allow you to do that. It is for in memory buffer size, not for disk.

See [vm/Profile.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/master/vm/Profile.cpp) line 383.

```
state->buf = (u1*) malloc(bufferSize);
```

Skip giving a buffer size. That will default it to 8MB, should be enough for your needs.

Comment: But if I do not specify anything, it only traces for about 500 ms? Can this be true? The file itself does not take up more space than 1230 KB if I do not give int argument. That is less than 8 mb, but if I just multiply the time interval, it will only allow tracing for about 2 seconds? (8/1.2 = 4, 4 * 500 ms = 2 seconds)

Comment: do you get a full dump? Probably your `stopMethodTracing` is never called and you pull some half baked file.

Comment: Thank you! I think you are right! The trace is not stopped. I assumed the stop method got called as I force the application to stop... Probably not the case. Seems like the Samsung is able to run the code now after I removed the int argument. Now it can trace for almost 20 seconds. The motorolla seems to trace for about 4 seconds.

Comment: add `Debug.stopMethodTracing();` to `onPause`, that'll be called when you move back to home screen or some other activity.